# The Reservation does not get deleted in the Database

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

We are building a car rental web App (Raact,css, Node.js) and the feature of deleting the reservation does not work. The user enters the right format which is 'A123456789'. This is the message shown on the screen: Failed to cancel reservation. Please try again later. The database is on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Below is the Code for CancelReservation.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function CancelReservation() {
    const [reservationId, setReservationId] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null); 
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const isFormatValidReservationId = (reservationId) => {
        const regex = /^[A-Z]{1}\d{9}$/;
        return regex.test(reservationId);
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setReservationId(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const reservationIdTrimmed = reservationId.trim(); // Trim the reservation ID

        if (!isFormatValidReservationId(reservationIdTrimmed)) {
            setError("Invalid reservation ID format");
            return;
        }
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:9000/reservations/${reservationIdTrimmed}`, {
                method: "DELETE",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Reservation successfully canceled');
                // Redirect to confirmation page or display success message
                navigate('/confirmation'); // Redirect to confirmation page
            } else {
                setError('Failed to cancel reservation. Please try again later.');
                console.error('Failed to cancel reservation:', response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError('An error occurred while cancelling the reservation. Please try again later.');
            console.error('Error cancelling reservation:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label> Reservation ID:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={reservationId} 
                    placeholder="Enter Reservation ID"
                    required
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
            <button type="submit">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default CancelReservation;
```

This is the code for handling the backend for reservations ReservationsRoute.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('../../database/db');

const router = express.Router();

// Create a new reservation
router.post('/reservations', async (req, res) => {
    const { id, vehicleID, customerID, pickUpDate, returnDate, extraEquipment, additionalServices, total} = req.body;
    const paid = 'false';
  
    try {
      // Insert new reservation
      const result = await pool.query`INSERT INTO Reservation (ID, Vehicle_ID, Customer_ID, Pick_Up_Date, Return_Date, Extra_Equipment, Additional_Services, Paid, Total) VALUES (${id}, ${vehicleID}, ${customerID}, ${pickUpDate}, ${returnDate}, ${extraEquipment}, ${additionalServices}, ${paid}, ${total})`;
  
      // Get existing Reservation_ID from Customer table
      const customerResult = await pool.query`SELECT Reservation_ID FROM Customers WHERE ID = ${customerID}`;
      const existingReservationID = customerResult.recordset[0].Reservation_ID;
  
      // Update Reservation_ID in Customer table by appending the new reservation ID
      const newReservationID = existingReservationID ? `${existingReservationID},${id}` : id;
      await pool.query`UPDATE Customers SET Reservation_ID = ${newReservationID} WHERE ID = ${customerID}`;
  
      res.status(201).json({ message: 'Reservation created successfully', reservation: req.body });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating reservation:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
    }
  });

// Get all reservation by user
router.get('/reservations/customer/:customerId', async (req, res) => {
    const customerId = req.params.customerId;

    try {
      const result = await pool.query`SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE ID = ${customerId}`;
      const reservations = result.recordsets;
  
      if (!reservations) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Reservations not found' });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({reservations : reservations}); // e.g. Reservations = response.body.reservations -> Reservations[#].Name
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving reservation:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
    }
  });

// Get a reservation by ID
router.get('/reservations/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const reservationId = req.params.id;

  try {
    const result = await pool.query`SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE ID = ${reservationId}`;
    const reservation = result.recordset[0];

    if (!reservation) {
      res.status(404).json({ error: 'Reservation not found' });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({reservation : reservation}); // e.g. Reservation = response.body.reservation -> Reservation.Name
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving reservation:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
  }
});

// Update a specific reservation by ID
router.put('/reservations/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const reservationId = req.params.id;
  const { vehicleID, customerID, pickUpDate, returnDate, extraEquipment, additionalServices, paid, total } = req.body;

  try {
    const result = await pool.query`UPDATE Reservation SET Vehicle_ID = ${vehicleID}, Customer_ID = ${customerID}, Pick_Up_Date = ${pickUpDate}, Return_Date = ${returnDate}, Extra_Equipment = ${extraEquipment}, Additional_Services = ${additionalServices}, Paid = ${paid}, Total = ${total} WHERE ID = ${reservationId}`;
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Reservation updated successfully',  reservation: req.body }); // e.g. Reservation = response.body.reservation -> Reservation.name
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating reservation:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
  }
});

// Delete a specific reservation by ID

router.delete('/reservations/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const reservationId = req.params.id;

  try {
      // Get Customer_ID 
      const customerResult = await pool.query`SELECT Customer_ID FROM Reservation WHERE ID = ${reservationId}`;
      if (customerResult.recordset.length === 0) {
          return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Reservation not found' });
      }
      const customerId = customerResult.recordset[0].Customer_ID;

      // Delete reservation
      const result = await pool.query`DELETE FROM Reservation WHERE ID = ${reservationId}`;

      // Get existing Reservation_ID from Customer table using the Customer's ID
      const customerResult2 = await pool.query`SELECT Reservation_ID FROM Customers WHERE ID = ${customerId}`;
      const existingReservationID = customerResult2.recordset[0]?.Reservation_ID;

      // Remove the deleted reservation ID from Reservation_ID in Customer table
      const updatedReservationID = existingReservationID
          ? existingReservationID.split(',').filter(id => id !== reservationId).join(',')
          : '';

      // Update Reservation_ID in Customer table
      await pool.query`UPDATE Customers SET Reservation_ID = ${updatedReservationID} WHERE ID = ${customerId}`;

      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Reservation deleted successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting Reservation:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the webpage Cancel.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import CancelReservation from '../components/CancelReservation';
import './../style/Cancel.css';

function Cancel() {
  return (
<div className="main-content">
  <div className="cancel-container">
    <h2 className="reservation-title">Cancel Reservation</h2>
      <div className="cancel-form"><CancelReservation/></div>
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default Cancel;
```

This is the App.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import SignUp from "./pages/SignUp";
import AdminDashboard from "./pages/AdminDashboard";
import CreateCRAccount from "./pages/CreateCRAccount";
import SignIn from "./pages/SignIn";
import Cancel from "./pages/Cancel";

function App() {

  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState("");

  const callAPI = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(res => {console.log(res); 
        setApiResponse(res
        )})
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }

  const callAPI2 = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/vehicles", {
      method: 'GET', 
    })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {console.log(data.vehicle[0][0]); // always keep data.vehicle[0] this will return you an arrray with all the vehilce
        setApiResponse(data                              // data.vehicle[0] = array of vehicles  -- data.vehicle[0][0] = 1st vehicle in the list -- data.vehicle[0][0].ID == ID of the first vehicle
        )})
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    callAPI();
    callAPI2();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once when the component mounts


  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/Cancel" exact element={<Cancel/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

We tried to look into the console on the webpage. It displays the following message: server error 404(Not Found) and 500 (Internal Server Error), the API is working properly. We also asked chatgpt and it said it was fine but clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

Often web servers will be configured to block anything except GET and POST since 99% of the time they're all that are needed and there have been problems in the past with applications assuming the requests were one of those two.

This happens because PUT and DELETE are part of WebDAV verbs and the WebDAV module claims incoming requests with these verbs and returns “405 Method not allowed” response.

I believe "**405 Method not allowed**" to be *quite* an inappropriate error message. It doesn't reflect any of the above three reasons and is very confusing.
I, moreover, believe that "400 Bad Request", "404 Not Found", or - rather - "501 Not Implemented" would have been rather more appropriate HTTP return states.

My personal suggestion use only GET and POST http methods, avoid using PUT and DELETE...

Hope this helps.